# Blue rounded 1x4 piece identification

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

There aren't any LEGO markings. Does anyone recognize the sticker? It's most likely from around 2013. I would like to know what set it is from. [image]

Comment: I am failing to identify the piece with bricklink...

Comment: That blue looks like a Lepin or MegaBlox, just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

The distance from the bottom right corner of the brick in your image to the top of the plate-part is 67px, which for [a plate is 3.2mm](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Lego_dimensions.svg). The full distance from the bottom right corner of the brick in your image to the top of the brick is 609px, which equates to 28.78mm, close enough to the 28.8mm a 3 brick-high piece would be (3 * 9.6mm). Well spotted @rschulz

[image: LEGO brick dimensions to tenth of a milimetre]

This is not LEGO. Searching for [1 x 4 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=1+x+4+x+3&rpp=100&tab=P#T=P) on BrickLink does not bring up any *Brick, Modifieds* that have rounded corners on one side, let alone a bottom plate. Nor are there any [1 x 4 *Plate, Modifieds*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Plate+modified+1+x+4+&type=P&rpp=100&tab=P#T=P) that have an addition like the above.

While LEGO pieces are well served with publicly accessible and searchable parts databases, MegaBlocks and their ilk are not. Your best bet - assuming this is a MegaBlocks part, and the part was stickered in accordance with whatever instructions come with the set - is a laborious search of a [MegaBlocks set database](https://bricker.info/), looking for an image of a 2 on a blue part of the model depicted on the box art.

Comment: To me, it looks more like a 1x4x3 <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=1+x+4+x+3>